# Cannot Create a Row of Size 8705 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

Tags: php, sql-server

I have some inherited code which basically produces a huge select statement such as"

```
SELECT 
table1.Field1 as table1.Field1, 
table1.Field2 as table1.Field2, 
table2.Field1 as table2.Field1, 
table2.Field2 as table2.Field2... 
etc...
```

And there's literally, around 800+ columns.

I was confused why on a SELECT, we're getting told the error:

Cannot Create a Row of Size 8705 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

Of course it makes sense because, although we're not INSERTing or UPDATing anything, we are, in essence, create a row in memory.

The select statement works fine on the SQL Server, and we're using the SQL ODBC driver v18 and PHP Driver 5.10.1 on Windows.

I've tried CAST(table2.Field2 AS NVARCHAR(250)) as table2.Field2, but that didn't have any impact. I don't particularly want to re-engineer anything at this stage. Unless there's something simple we can do it seems our option can be to remove fields from the selection list.

Any other potential quick wins?

Comment: Does SELECT * FROM... work?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "The select statement works fine on the SQL Server"? Do you mean it runs successfully from SSMS but not the php code?

Comment: It is a basic limit of Microsoft SQL Server. You may refer to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/07d14670-494e-4b6f-bf1c-db0d52780bc8/cannot-create-a-row-of-size-8064-which-is-greater-than-the-allowable-maximum-row-size-of-8060?forum=sqldataaccess) for some suggested workarounds

Comment: Are you trying to `SELECT ... INTO` another table? There is no such limitation for a `SELECT` query though if the execution plan needs to create a work table (e.g. for a sort or spool) you may get an error then

Comment: Yes Dan, it works in SSMS, but not frm the PHP Code. Martin, no not SELECT ... INTO. Such an odd problem. I think though as we're using a static rather than buffered cursor, or maybe the PHP driver is doing something different to SSMS, SQL is trying to build a "temporary table" itself to return the results but cannot due to the 8060 limit. The main thing here is that the error doesn't match the query.